# Estimate arrival time of a ship given the average of the ships in a day in a Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, simulation

I'm working in a simulation of a Port where ships come to specific stations of the port. I already know that the average amount of ships is given by a Poisson distribution and the service time (On each station of the port) is given by a normal distribution.

Is there any way to estimate the time between each ship that comes to the station? given that the average amount of ships in a day (24 hours) is given by the Poisson distribution. So far I think is hard to estimate, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does the Poisson parameter represent the average at a particular station or the whole port?

Comment: Yes, it does represent it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is described by exponential distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution. Briefly, if $\lambda$ the mean of your Poisson distribution, namely the averaged number of ships per day, then $1/\lambda$ is the averaged time ( in day units) between ships.. Very natural.

Comment: Does this answer account for the normal distribution of the service times?

Comment: Is quite correct to use that averaged time (1/λ) and compute Poisson with that average to estimate a random arrival time?, or its better to assign the average time to each ship?

Comment: You were asking "the time between each ship that comes to the station". Service time is not related to this . If you mean something different - explain clearer. My answer is to your question. I don't understand why somebody considers this answer incorrect.

Comment: @TimDuff How would the time to service ships *in* the station affect the rate of arrival of ships *to* the station?  That would be an issue of queuing; a different question.

Comment: I just put the time service with the intent of put the problem in context.